# R mad() and base code return different answers on same vector

Tags: r, mean

I am working some exercises with statistical functions. When calculating the Mean Absolute Deviation of a vector, `mad()` and the `base R` code calculation where different:

```
x <- c(2, 3, 6, 8, 11)  
# R function  
mad(x, center = median(x), constant = 1)  
# [1] 3  

# Base code  
sum(abs(x - mean(x)))/length(x)  
[1] 2.8
```

However, when applied to a sequence, both options returned the same answer:

```
x <- 1:10   
# R function  
mad(x, center = median(x), constant = 1)   
# [1] 2.5  

# Base code  
sum(abs(x - mean(x)))/length(x)   
# [1] 2.5
```

Why the inconsistency?

Comment: The median and the mean are not generally the same - except in special cases such as a sequence of evenly-spaced values.

Comment: Note `mad()` is "*median* absolute deviation," not "mean absolute deviation" as stated in your post. So the appropriate code to test it against would be `median(abs(x - median(x)))`, which does give the same result as `mad()`.

Comment: Thanks, zephryl, but putting 'mean' in base code instead of 'median' was an oversight when posting the question. Even when # Base code  sum(abs(x - median(x)))/length(x)  it still returns 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Because it uses a different formula for the MAD when the data has a median of 0 than the formula used in the base code calculation. This is why the two methods produced different results for the vector x.

though for the sequence 1:10, which has a median of 5.5, both methods produced the same result because the mad() function uses the same formula as the base code calculation in this case.

Comment: Thanks, but then, when to use which?